# Error: Invalid method Mage_Customer_Block_Form_Login

Tags: ce-1.7.0.2

i have problem with costumer Account

The account login page isn't work .. Any ideas?

Error: Invalid method Mage_Customer_Block_Form_Login

Invalid method Mage_Customer_Block_Form_Login::quoteEscape(Array
(
    [0] => Account aanmaken
)
)

Trace:

## 0 /app/design/frontend/base/default/template/recaptcha/persistent/customer/form/login.phtml(59): Varien_Object->__call('quoteEscape', Array)

## 1 /app/design/frontend/base/default/template/recaptcha/persistent/customer/form/login.phtml(59): Mage_Customer_Block_Form_Login->quoteEscape('Account aanmake...')

## 2 /app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Template.php(241): include('/home/darekli2/...')

## 3 /app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Template.php(272): Mage_Core_Block_Template->fetchView('frontend/base/d...')

## 4 /app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Template.php(286): Mage_Core_Block_Template->renderView()

## 5 /app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Abstract.php(863): Mage_Core_Block_Template->_toHtml()

## 6 /app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Text/List.php(43): Mage_Core_Block_Abstract->toHtml()

## 7 /app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Abstract.php(863): Mage_Core_Block_Text_List->_toHtml()

## 8 /app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Abstract.php(582): Mage_Core_Block_Abstract->toHtml()

## 9 /app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Abstract.php(526): Mage_Core_Block_Abstract->_getChildHtml('content', true)

## 10 /app/design/frontend/default/kallyas/template/page/1column.phtml(58): Mage_Core_Block_Abstract->getChildHtml('content')

## 11 /app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Template.php(241): include('/home/darekli2/...')

## 12 /app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Template.php(272): Mage_Core_Block_Template->fetchView('frontend/defaul...')

## 13 /app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Template.php(286): Mage_Core_Block_Template->renderView()

## 14 /app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Abstract.php(863): Mage_Core_Block_Template->_toHtml()

## 15 /app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Layout.php(555): Mage_Core_Block_Abstract->toHtml()

## 16 /app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Action.php(390): Mage_Core_Model_Layout->getOutput()

## 17 /app/code/core/Mage/Customer/controllers/AccountController.php(131): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Action->renderLayout()

## 18 /app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Action.php(419): Mage_Customer_AccountController->loginAction()

## 19 /app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Router/Standard.php(250): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Action->dispatch('login')

## 20 /app/code/community/BalkeTechnologies/StoreMaintenance/Controller/Router/Standard.php(91): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Router_Standard->match(Object(Mage_Core_Controller_Request_Http))

## 21 /app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Front.php(176): BalkeTechnologies_StoreMaintenance_Controller_Router_Standard->match(Object(Mage_Core_Controller_Request_Http))

## 22 /app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/App.php(354): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Front->dispatch()

## 23 /app/Mage.php(683): Mage_Core_Model_App->run(Array)

## 24 /index.php(87): Mage::run('', 'store')

## 25 {main}

Comment: Disabling reCaptcha fixed the site